# I get a pygame error after a quit my pygame window

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to understand how to display fonts in pygame. But i get an error saying pygame.error: Library not initialized

This error happens after i press the cross button or quit my pygame window.

Can anyone tell my why this error is happening and how can i fix it please?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
pygame.init()
WIDTH = GetSystemMetrics(0)
HEIGHT = GetSystemMetrics(1)-64
WIDTH_HEIGHT = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)

WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode(WIDTH_HEIGHT)
pygame.init()
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
text = ""

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False
    text = font.render('Hi', True, (255,255,255))
    WINDOW.blit(text, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: it seems that it is because You quit pygame but the loop continues to run, until the end so since You have quit pygame the font is no more initialised, usually `pygame.quit()` is put outside and after the `while` loop. and leave just the `running = False` in the if statement

Comment: Ok, so what if after pygame.quit() i write sys.exit()

Comment: don't, first of it would be better to just use `exit()`, second there is no point to use `pygame.quit()` at that point, I will give YOu examples

Comment: Ok thanks you solved my problem but if there any diffrence between exit() and sys.exit()?

Comment: yes, there is, `exit()` is "softer" and `sys.exit()` just shuts it

Comment: Thanks I understood it

Comment: probably better if You just google what is the difference since I won't be able to explain too well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to exit (just finishes the program):

```
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            
pygame.quit()
```

This is another way (a bit more forceful):

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```